# Icon not displayed correctly in setup project VS 2005

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2005, icons, setup-project, addremoveprograms

I am making a setup project for my dependent project in the same solution, i have a icon for my dependent project which i set in project properties, i have also added this icon to setup project in the application folder, i want this icon to appear in the add/remove programs dialog but so far only default no icon is appearing.

this .ico file has multiple size images in it when i open this file in VS2008 image of all size appear and when i open this file in VS2005 only 32 x 32 image appears. what might be happening?

Comment: got it, setup project has a property Add/remove programs icon. just set the property and you are good to go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Visual Studio 2005 doesnt support Vista Icons in its applications, there is a workaround to this problem here: http://bliny.net/blog/post/Vista-256x256-compressed-icons-with-VS-2005.aspx